# Where is dnsmasq started and configured?

Tags: 10.04, server, networking

Where is dnsmasq started and configured during the system startup under Ubuntu Lucid server?

I have not been able to find any startup script or service that actually starts and sets up dnsmasq.

I would like to get rid of the dhcp service, or prevent it from starting altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dnsmasq startup script is `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq`.  It's called by symlinks from the /etc/rcX.d/ directories, for example: `/etc/rc2.d/S15dnsmasq`

If you don't want it to start, you can remove the package with `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq`.  Or you can leave it installed and just remove all symlinks from the /etc/rcX.d/ directories with the command: `update-rc.d -f dnsmasq remove`.

You can also edit `/etc/default/dnsmasq` and change "ENABLED=1" to "ENABLED=0" which will also tell it not to run in daemon mode.

Lastly, you can disable just the DHCP function by editing `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and adding lines for your interfaces that you don't want DHCP on by adding, for example: "no-dhcp-interface=eth0".  You might do this if you still wanted to use the DNS functionality.

Note:  sometimes dnsmasq is installed as `dnsmasq-base` instead of `dnsmasq` in order to work with other packages such as NetworkManager (when sharing an internet connection) or Libvirt (for giving addresses to virtual machines).

Comment: When I started answering, I really didn't think there would be 4 different answers.  That's kinda nuts.

Comment: Hate to say it, but the dnsmasq package isn't installed, nor do any of the files you indicated exist.  Nevertheless dnsmasq is up and running.

Comment: Find the path to the binary (`which dnsmasq` is one way) and then run the command: `dpkg -S /path/to/dnsmasq`.  This will tell you which package owns that file.

Comment: dnsmasq comes from the dnsmasq-base package which was a dep of libvirt-bin.  Since I'm not setting up any virtual servers I'm guessing I can remove libvirt and friends.

Comment: Indeed.  Could you do me a favor and mark the answer correct?  :)

Comment: How do I add it so it starts at boot?

Comment: i tried all but it did not work. some how dnsmasq is started at boot.

any other options?

Comment: ps i'm on debian

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions, I don't want to uninstall the libvirt package so

I either disable  it in:

/etc/default/libvirt-bin:

```
start_libvirtd="no"
```

Or edit:

/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf

```
#start on (runlevel [2345] and stopped networking RESULT=ok)
start on runlevel [45]
```

Comment: I'm unsure what "and stopped networking RESULT=ok" actually does.